# Solspace Super Search - inclusive_keywords="no" not working

Tags: solspace

We have a keywords search url as follows:

```
http://localhost/search/results/search&keywords=kite+apple
```

We have an entry called 'kite', but not one called 'apple'. This search results request returns 'no results found'. If we remove the 'apple' variable, it returns the 'kite' entry fine.

We are using the `inclusive_keywords="no"` parameter, so I would have expected the 'kite' entry to be returned with or without the 'apple'.

Any help would be gratefully received.

Jonathan

Comment: What version of EE and Super Search are you using? Can you show us your template code for your search form and results? you can add this by editing the opening post.